# Centering icon and text

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Im having a hard time centering a `text` with `awesome font icon`, and also centering the icons themselves.

> Im using styled components like so:

```
const StyledIcon = styled(FontAwesomeIcon)`
    width: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
`;
const Text = styled.div`
    font-size: 13px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`;
```

> and in my component I have the following

```
<StyledIcon icon={icon1} />
<Text>Charts + Graphs</Text>

<StyledIcon icon={icon2} />
<Text>Classes</Text>

<StyledIcon icon={icon3} />
<Text>Student Information</Text>

<StyledIcon icon={icon4} />
<Text>Knowledge Database</Text>

<StyledIcon icon={icon5}/>
<Text>Class Notes</Text>
```

This is how it currently looks, any suggestions on how to center text & icon so that they appear in the center of the shaded box?
[image]

Comment: can you post a fiddle replicating the issue you have? Looks like your sizes are wrong, also you may need to apply `align-items` to the css as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox.

```
const WrapperAroundIconsAndText = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
`;
```